# is it possible to set userInfo in SBApplication from Springboard tweak?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, logos

is it possible to set userInfo in SBApplication from Springboard tweak, so when app launches i can catch it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change existing question. If you want, ask another question. You completely changed your question and now my answer is useless for those who will find it later.

As for the new question, you can write tweak that loads with every application that links to `UIKit.framework`. To do this you need to add MobileSubstrate filter

```
Filter = {
    Bundles = (com.apple.UIKit);
};
```

In your tweak you can hook `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions` and pass any arguments you want.

More information about MobileSubstrate filters can be found here http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate

Comment: thanks a lot! sorry for changing question, may be we can delete your previous answer or i can edit question to relate to your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think there is `userInfo` variable inside `bulletin` object? Assuming it is an instance of class `SBBulletinBannerItem` there is no `userInfo` variable. Even if it's instance of `BBBulletin` still there is no `userInfo` variable.